# Error converting pandas grouped column into string

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to convert a grouped column of a pandas frame into a string:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date' : ['2018-01-01','2018-01-01','2018-01-02','2018-01-02'], 
        'product' : ['apple','banana','banana','pear'],
        'price' : [100,200,300,400]
    })

grouped_df =  df.groupby('date').agg({'product': ['unique'], 'price': ['sum']}).reset_index()
grouped_df['product'] = grouped_df['product'].apply(  lambda l: ";".join(l.tolist()) )
print(grouped_df.to_csv(header=False))
```

The goal is to output `apple;banana` in the CSV instead of `['apple', 'banana']` but when I try to run `grouped_df['product'].apply(  lambda l: ";".join(l.tolist()) )`, I get a `TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.ndarray found', 'occurred at index unique')`.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
grouped_df['product'] = grouped_df['product']['unique'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x))

>>> grouped_df
         date       product price
                     unique   sum
0  2018-01-01  apple;banana   300
1  2018-01-02   banana;pear   700
```

The issue was that you were trying to access a multi-level column, but skipping over the `unique` level. So what you were accessing was actually a `DataFrame`, but you wanted to access a `Series`:

```
>>> type(grouped_df['product'])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>>> type(grouped_df['product']['unique'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```